# Updating with a select one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update a column with a concatenation of other columns within the same table.

This is for customer names in a table. There are separate columns for "Title" i.e. Mr, Ms, Mrs etc, "FirstName", "MiddleName" and "LastName". I altered the table by adding a new "FullName" column, which I tried to fill with a concatenation of the former columns.

```
SET [SalesLT].[Customer].[FullName] = (SELECT 
    Title, 
    FirstName, 
    MiddleName, 
    LastName,
    CONCAT(Title,' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) as FullName
FROM [AdventureWorksLT2008R2].[SalesLT].[Customer])
WHERE FullName = NULL;
```

I'm getting this

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: You also can use calculate column and save it in the table for the formula, so that will make it much easier to use

Comment: Definitely better to make it a computed column, then you don't have to ensure you keep your new column in sync with changes in data.

Comment: For SQL Server you need `FullName is null` *not* `FullName = null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating a column value based on other columns in the same table, you not select them again.

```
UPDATE [SalesLT].[Customer]
SET [SalesLT].[Customer].[FullName] = 
    CONCAT(Title,' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName)
WHERE FullName is NULL;
```

**Note:** I did not change your where clause condition, neither concat function. In some databases you may need to do `FullName is NULL` instead of `FullName = NULL`. And in some databases, you may need to concat multiple values with `||`.